# Crear copias de imágenes para agregarle la palabra "thumbnail " al nombre de archivo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Tengo el siguiente árbol de archivos;

```
articles-assets
 ┣ 12
 ┃ ┣ 87c2b858-9800-4a63-9fb5-3ffff2d7158d.jpg
 ┃ ┣ 8a260feb-a6a9-4479-af2b-1de6a9fd278f.jpg
 ┃ ┣ 94b74cac-fb8d-425c-8179-ca7ad0797275.jpg
 ┣ 38
 ┃ ┣ 02778a12-7b62-4ef1-b325-8ec007438282.jpg
 ┃ ┣ 0e54a466-0ede-4570-8de1-f5170655f9cb.jpg
 ┃ ┣ 158f7750-491e-49ac-ba07-c34b07c952c2.jpg
 ┃ ┣ 386e6bf5-226c-4602-bed2-43163d5071ce.jpg
 ┣ 39
 ┃ ┣ 09db5250-b0e6-4ae8-8523-1ab20a6bfa8f.jpg
 ┃ ┣ 1327af15-3056-42ae-a175-1032ce5f2d12.jpg
 ┗ 40
 ┃ ┣ 09588bf7-4622-42b2-8262-5696a1b1283a.jpg
 ┃ ┣ 48dc8e7e-ffcb-4ab3-9ddc-85263861d74f.jpg
```

y quisiera mediante la linea de comandos poder crear una copia de cada archivo en el directorio al que cada uno pertenece y agregarle la palabra "thumbnail" antes de cada nombre.

un resultado seria este:

```
 ┗ 40
 ┃ ┣ 09588bf7-4622-42b2-8262-5696a1b1283a.jpg
 ┃ ┣ 48dc8e7e-ffcb-4ab3-9ddc-85263861d74f.jpg
 ┃ ┣ thumbnail-09588bf7-4622-42b2-8262-5696a1b1283a.jpg # modificado
 ┃ ┣ thumbnail-48dc8e7e-ffcb-4ab3-9ddc-85263861d74f.jpg # modificado
```

Comment: faltaría indicar qué intentaste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar:

```
$ find articles-assets -type f \
    | xargs -P0 -I % bash -c 'cp % $(cut -d "/" -f -2 <<< %)/thumbnail-$(cut -d "/" -f 3 <<< %)'
```

Y de una estructura así:

```
articles-assets
├── 12
│   ├── 87c2b858-9800-4a63-9fb5-3ffff2d7158d.jpg
│   ├── 8a260feb-a6a9-4479-af2b-1de6a9fd278f.jpg
│   └── 94b74cac-fb8d-425c-8179-ca7ad0797275.jpg
├── 38
│   ├── 02778a12-7b62-4ef1-b325-8ec007438282.jpg
│   ├── 0e54a466-0ede-4570-8de1-f5170655f9cb.jpg
│   ├── 158f7750-491e-49ac-ba07-c34b07c952c2.jpg
...
```

Obtendrás:

```
    articles-assets
├── 12
│   ├── 87c2b858-9800-4a63-9fb5-3ffff2d7158d.jpg
│   ├── 8a260feb-a6a9-4479-af2b-1de6a9fd278f.jpg
│   ├── 94b74cac-fb8d-425c-8179-ca7ad0797275.jpg
│   ├── thumbnail-87c2b858-9800-4a63-9fb5-3ffff2d7158d.jpg
│   ├── thumbnail-8a260feb-a6a9-4479-af2b-1de6a9fd278f.jpg
│   └── thumbnail-94b74cac-fb8d-425c-8179-ca7ad0797275.jpg
├── 38
│   ├── 02778a12-7b62-4ef1-b325-8ec007438282.jpg
│   ├── 0e54a466-0ede-4570-8de1-f5170655f9cb.jpg
│   ├── 158f7750-491e-49ac-ba07-c34b07c952c2.jpg
│   ├── 386e6bf5-226c-4602-bed2-43163d5071ce.jpg
│   ├── thumbnail-02778a12-7b62-4ef1-b325-8ec007438282.jpg
│   ├── thumbnail-0e54a466-0ede-4570-8de1-f5170655f9cb.jpg
│   ├── thumbnail-158f7750-491e-49ac-ba07-c34b07c952c2.jpg
│   └── thumbnail-386e6bf5-226c-4602-bed2-43163d5071ce.jpg
...
```

El comando:

```
find articles-assets -type f
```

Busca archivos "normales" dentro de la carpeta.

Luego, con:

```
xargs -P0 -I % bash -c 'cp % $(cut -d "/" -f -2 <<< %)/thumbnail-$(cut -d "/" -f 3 <<< %)'
```

Hacemos que `xargs` pase el nombre de cada archivo a un proceso de bash. Dentro de este, hacemos la copia y el renombre utilizando la posición del delimitador `/`.

### Actualización

Creo que de esta manera es un tanto más clara y eficiente:

```
$ find articles-assets -type f \
    | xargs -P0 -I % bash -c 'cp % $(dirname %)/thumbnail-$(basename %)'
```

Aquí no usamos las posiciones, sino simplemente obtenemos el nombre del directorio (con `dirname`), añadimos el prefijo, y completamos con el nombre del archivo (con `basename`).

Comment: Excelente explicación, funciono perfecto. Muchas gracias.